# Tf-idf for SO posts (where tag can only occur once )

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf

Using the stackoverflow data dump, I am analyzing SO posts that are tagged with pytorch or keras. Specifically, I count how many times each co tag occurs (ie the tags that aren't pytorch in a pytorch tagged post).

I'd like to filter out the tags that are so common they've lost real meaning for my analysis (like the python tag).

I am looking into Tf-idf

TF reprensents the frequency of word for each document. However, each co-tag can only occur once for a given post (ie you can't tag your post 'html' five times). So the tf for most words would be 1/5, and others less (because post only has 4 tags for instance). Is it still possible to do Tf-Idf given this context?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out tags that are so common, you can use `conditional probability`. eg: `python` is so common on posts taged `pytorch`, so P(python|pytorch) will be hight, likes:0.9. You can find a threshold to filter those tags. 
`Association rule learning` is more suitable and more complex than the above.